# Extracting subset of character string between special characters

Tags: r, regex, string

Let’s say I have a string:

```
“Region/Country/Industry/Product”
```

I only want to extract the characters between the n-th and m-th single slash. Is there a one-liner using an existing function which we can use to do that?

For example, if I wanted to get the string between the 2nd and 3rd slashes for entries in the following character vector:

```
c(“EMEA/Germany/Automotive/Mercedes”, “APAC/SouthKorea/Technology/Samsung”, 
  “AMER/US/Wireless/Verizon”)
```

the output with such a function would be:

```
c(“Automotive”,”Technology”,”Wireless”).
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `sub` to capture the word before the last `/`, in the replacement, specify the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub(".*[/](\\w+)[/]\\w+$", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "Automotive" "Technology" "Wireless"
```

Or another variation is

```
sub("^([^/]+[/]){2}([^/]+).*", "\\2", str1)
#[1] "Automotive" "Technology" "Wireless"
```

---

Or split the string at the delimiter `/` and extract the words

```
sapply(strsplit(str1, "/"), `[`, 3)
#[1] "Automotive" "Technology" "Wireless"
```

#### data

```
str1 <-  c("EMEA/Germany/Automotive/Mercedes", 
      "APAC/SouthKorea/Technology/Samsung", "AMER/US/Wireless/Verizon")
```

Answer (score 3):

Of course the `stringr` solution,

```
library(stringr)
word(x, 3, sep = '/')
#[1] "Automotive" "Technology" "Wireless"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the function `strsplit` like below and costomise the position

```
x <- c("EMEA/Germany/Automotive/Mercedes", "APAC/SouthKorea/Technology/Samsung", "AMER/US/Wireless/Verizon")
sapply(x, FUN = function(x) {
    y <- unlist(strsplit(x, split="/"))
    y[3] # This line can be customised depending the position of the word
    }
)
# "Automotive"                       "Technology"                         "Wireless"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove the parts you don't want:

```
strings <- c("EMEA/Germany/Automotive/Mercedes", "APAC/SouthKorea/Technology/Samsung","AMER/US/Wireless/Verizon")

gsub("^([^/]*/){2}|/[^/]*$","",strings)

#[1] "Automotive" "Technology" "Wireless"
```